# При запуске бота, написанного на Spring java, всё проходит хорошо, а потом программа завершается со статусом 0

Tags: java, spring, telegrambots

Не работает код, пошарил в отладке, бот почему-то `null`, помогите чем можете.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>org.testbot</groupId>
        <artifactId>SpringTestBot</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>SpringTestBot</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties>
        
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
                
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
                <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.30</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>        
        
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
   </project>
```

```java
package org.testbot.SpringTestBot.service;
            
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.commands.SetMyCommands;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.updatingmessages.EditMessageText;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.commands.BotCommand;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.commands.scope.BotCommandScopeDefault;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.InlineKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.InlineKeyboardButton;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardRow;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.testbot.SpringTestBot.config.BotConfig;
            
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
            
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    final BotConfig config;

    public TelegramBot(BotConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
        List<BotCommand> listofCommands = new ArrayList<>();
        listofCommands.add(new BotCommand("/start", "get a welcome message"));
    }
            
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return config.getBotName();
    }
    public String getBotToken() { return config.getToken();}

    @Override
    // обработка соо от пользователя и ответ на них
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String msgText = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            switch (msgText) {
                case "/start":
                    startCommandReceived(chatId, update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
                    break;
                case "/help":
                    helpCommandReceived(chatId);
                    break;
                default:
                    sendMsg(chatId,"Неверное сообщение ");
            }
        }
    }

    private void startCommandReceived(Long chatId,String name) {
        String answer = "Привет, " + name + ", я твой бот";
        sendMsg(chatId,answer);
    }

    private void helpCommandReceived(Long chatId) {
        String answer = " Я помогаю тебе";
        sendMsg(chatId,answer);
    }

    private void sendMsg(long chatId,String textToSend) {
        SendMessage msg = new SendMessage();
        msg.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
        msg.setText(textToSend);
        try {
            execute(msg);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package org.testbot.SpringTestBot;
        
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication; 

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTestBotApplication {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTestBotApplication.class, args);
    }    
}
```

```java
package org.testbot.SpringTestBot.config;
    
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
        
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@Data
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class BotConfig {
        
    @Value("${bot.name}")
    String botName;
        
    @Value("${bot.token}")
    String token;
}
```

Начал что-то исправлять, ещё хуже всё сломал

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-23T23:11:15.323+03:00 ERROR 10340 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375) И покажите ваш код целиком.

Comment: Следует смотреть код _до момента вызова_ метода `registerBot`.  И укажите хотя бы какую библиотеку используете.

Comment: Так _всё проходит хорошо_, или выбрасывается исключение из-за `null`-ового бота?

Comment: Проходит хорошо, просто показалось, что может работать некорректно из-за этого null, использую lombok, telegrambots, spring-boot-starter-test и spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, как так получилось, но после того, как переписал весь код заново начало работать корректно, возможно была неправильно собрана компоновка в спринг